# How to apply an effect on screen image in Windows on the fly?

Tags: windows, graphics, driver, hardware, monitor

I'm developing a Windows application that needs to apply an effect on screen image. More specifically, I need to do the following: grab a screen image, apply a gaussian blur on it, and display it on the screen. Something similar to f.lux, only in my case the effect applied is different.

Since I'm new in Windows development, I'd like to know what is the recommended way to do it? What libraries/frameworks should I use? Can you point to some code samples of similar applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you must use C# and .net?

Comment: No. I would prefer it because it I'm more comfortable with it than C/C++, but any solution would do. I'll remove these tags to avoid confusion.

Comment: What kind of application are we talking about? Are there real-time constraints? Does the user still need to interact with the blurred image, i.e. do you just want to blur the desktop via an overlay?

Comment: The application will be used in a psychology experiment. The subject will use a computer as usual, but screen image will be blurred. The amplitude of the blur must be changeable in real time so application changes it based on input it receives.

Comment: I fear this will be really hard (if possible at all). If you rely on window applications, the window manager will probably make your life very difficult (window focus, input routing...) It could work with a display filter driver. So instead of manipulating the system, just manipulate the output. I have no experience in driver development, but I can imagine that this should be possible. But be sure to let the graphics driver do its work before manipulating the output.